# sonar to get Java Unit Test Results and details from sonar-project.properties

Tags: unit-testing

i am trying to get Unit Test Details(No. of Test cases and success and failure % in Sonar), currently i am able to get "Code Coverage".. But not able to get Unit Test details... below my sonar-project.properties, i built projects using ant script for multiple projects..

When i run this sonar-runner getting 
INFO: Sensor SurefireSensor
INFO: parsing C:\dev\workspaces\base\customer\target\surefire-reports
ERROR: Reports path not found or is not a directory: C:\dev\workspaces\base\customer\target\surefire-reports

my queries are.. (1) how to tell sonar-runner to look on my 'common.sonar.surefire.reportsPath' (2) how to get Unit Test details in Sonar from sonar-project.properties. 
Please suggests.. Thanks for your time..

```
**sonar-project.properties**

sonar.projectBaseDir=C:/dev/workspaces/base/customer

sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports

# Modules List
sonar.modules=common,mobile

# common
common.sonar.projectBaseDir=C:/dev/workspaces/base/customer
common.sonar.sources=common/src/main/java
common.sonar.tests=common/src/test/java
common.sonar.java.binaries=common/bin
common.sonar.junit.reportsPath=common/test/reports/junitreport   
common.sonar.surefire.reportsPath=common/test/reports/junitreport
common.sonar.jacoco.reportPath=common/coverage/common.exec

# mobile
mobile.sonar.projectBaseDir=C:/dev/workspaces/base/customer
mobile.sonar.sources=mobile/src/main/java
mobile.sonar.tests=mobile/src/test/java
mobile.sonar.java.binaries=mobile/bin
mobile.sonar.junit.reportsPath=mobile/test/reports/junitreport   
mobile.sonar.surefire.reportsPath=mobile/test/reports/junitreport
mobile.sonar.jacoco.reportPath=mobile/coverage/mobile.exec
```

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the issue.. by updating the junit.reportsPath properties  ..common.sonar.junit.reportsPath=common/test/reports/junit
mobile.sonar.junit.reportsPath=mobile/test/reports/junit